# substitute other items' values as substrings

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

In a dictionary

```
{'A':'x', 'B':'y', 'C':'{A}_foo', 'D':'bar_{B}'}
```

, how would you perform a substitution producing

```
{'A':'x', 'B':'y', 'C':'x_foo', 'D':'bar_y'}
```

? No nesting like `'C':'{A}_foo', 'D':'oops_{C}'`, no recursion.

(This is a reduced example. In reality, it needs to happen row by row in a pandas dataframe)

Comment: post a dataframe and your initial code

Comment: Surely better options than using regex. However with PyPI regex module you could capture inside a variable length lookbehind: [`{(\w+)}(?<='\1':'(\w+)'.*)`](http://www.regexstorm.net/tester?p=%7B%28%5Cw%2B%29%7D%28%3F%3C%3D%27%5C1%27%3A%27%28%5Cw%2B%29%27.*%29&i=%7B%27A%27%3A%27x%27%2C%20%27B%27%3A%27y%27%2C%20%27C%27%3A%27%7BA%7D_foo%27%2C%20%27D%27%3A%27bar_%7BB%7D%27%7D&r=%242) and replace with what's captured by **group 2**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Python string formatting and expand the `d1` dict as the arguments:

```
d1={'A':'x', 'B':'y', 'C':'{A}_foo', 'D':'bar_{B}'}
d2={k:v.format(v,**d1) for k,v in d1.items()}

>>> d2
{'A': 'x', 'B': 'y', 'C': 'x_foo', 'D': 'bar_y'}
```

However, there is a *potential* of key errors here. Consider:

```
>>> d1={'A':'x', 'B':'y', 'C':'{A}_foo', 'D':'bar_{B}', 'E':'no-key_{Z}'}
>>> d2={k:v.format(v,**d1) for k,v in d1.items()}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
KeyError: 'Z'
```

If you want to gracefully handle key errors, you can subclass Formatter like so:

```
import string
class PartialFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, missing='~~', bad_fmt='!!'):
        self.missing, self.bad_fmt=missing, bad_fmt

    def get_field(self, field_name, args, kwargs):
        # Handle a key not found
        try:
            val=super(PartialFormatter, self).get_field(field_name, args, kwargs)
            # Python 3, 'super().get_field(field_name, args, kwargs)' works
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            val=None,field_name 
        return val 

    def format_field(self, value, spec):
        # handle an invalid format
        if value==None: return self.missing
        try:
            return super(PartialFormatter, self).format_field(value, spec)
        except ValueError:
            if self.bad_fmt is not None: return self.bad_fmt   
            else: raise

d1={'A':'x', 'B':'y', 'C':'{A}_foo', 'D':'bar_{B}', 'E':'no-key_{Z}'}
d2={}

fmt=PartialFormatter()
for k,v in d1.items():
    if '{' in v:
        d2[k]=fmt.format(v,**d1)
    else:
        d2[k]=v
```

Then you just silently get `~~` instead of a `KeyError`:

```
>>> d2
{'A': 'x', 'B': 'y', 'C': 'x_foo', 'D': 'bar_y', 'E': 'no-key_~~'}
```

Which can be modified to the behavior you desire...

---

Or, perhaps better still, use `try / except`:

```
d1={'A':'x', 'B':'y', 'C':'{A}_foo', 'D':'bar_{B}', 'E':'bad-fmt_{:B}', 'F':'no-key_{Z}'}
d2={}

for k,v in d1.items():
    if '{' in v:
        try:
            d2[k]=v.format(v,**d1)
        except (KeyError, ValueError):
            d2[k]=v 
    else:
        d2[k]=v    

>>> d2
{'A': 'x', 'B': 'y', 'C': 'x_foo', 'D': 'bar_y', 'E': 'bad-fmt_{:B}', 'F': 'no-key_{Z}'}
```

Comment: @dawg [Your answer is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390279/if-an-edit-to-an-answer-substantially-changes-that-answer-to-make-it-a-duplica)

Comment: Excellent answer. Showing both a simple solution and then also the importance of error checking and how to implement it is very helpful.

Comment: Believe it or not, the choice of curly brackets was purely incidental, not knowing much about format(). Thanks for your great answers.

Answer (score 3):

With a list comprehension on `d.items`, we can apply `val.format(**d)` on each value to interpolate the values with the dict itself:

> ```
> >>> d = {'A':'x', 'B':'y', 'C':'{A}_foo', 'D':'bar_{B}'}
> >>> o = dict([ (key, val.format(**d)) for key,val in d.items() ])
> >>> print (o)
> {'A': 'x', 'B': 'y', 'C': 'x_foo', 'D': 'bar_y'}
> ```